# Moving users to a different VC discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I have created a discord bot that does various functions. I would like for it to be able to move users. However, going on the official discordpy website and trying to read the documentation has not helped. I have looked at the answers provided here and still no solution.

So far I tried this:

```js
await client.move_member(id, channel)
```

```js
await member.move_to(channel)
```

Comment: Are you using discord.py or the rewrite? Each has a different version.

Comment: I am using discord.py, to be more accurate, I use ctx. Example being ctx.send("message").

Comment: `pip show discord.py` which version is it showing there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its important that you get all required discord models for the command to work. If you use the [commands extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) this command moves any number of members to another voice channel:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command()
async def move(ctx, members:commands.Greedy[discord.Member], *, channel:discord.VoiceChannel):
  for member in members:
    await member.move_to(channel=channel)
```

Example usage: `move @Someone @SomeoneElse VoiceChannelA`

Unfortunately, voice channels can't be specified by # so you have to type the name exactly. Also this `commands.Greedy` approach has some issues, so you might want to improve this command or add good error handling: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#greedy